# How can i calculate aspects of planets?

Tags: python

assuming that it has a database with all the longitudinal degrees of each planet inside it.

So for every day of the year I would have a similar result:

```
Sun:     135.45°
Mars:     29.72°
Jupiter:  56.89°
Uranus:   45.27°
Pluto:   165.78°
Venus:    89.34°
Mercury: 312.22°
Saturn:  267.86°
Moon:     92.78°
Earth:    33.23°
```

in which way could I calculate mathematically the aspects between every planet? By aspects I mean when a planet is 90° opposite from its current position, or -90°.
Same situation for an aspect from 60°, 30° and so on.

More than a python problem is a logic problem, I'm asking someone with more experience for help. I state that I am not using any astrological library, up to this point.

I can convert database values ​​to any form (list, tuple, dictionary)

Comment: "More than a python problem is a logic problem" - more like math, I would say. But either way, it is not on topic here - there is only a Stack Overflow question if you have difficulty *implementing* a formula; we don't deal with figuring out the project's requirements. Consider [math.se].

Comment: Well Karl, I knew I'd end up with a warn. However in the past I asked the same question using the hashtag math and it wasn't accepted either. However thank you because I didn't know that section, I'll try to take a look inside. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the aspects between planets, you need to compare the longitudinal degrees to which you have access with the other planets. This can be done by subtracting the degrees from one planet from another and then modulo with 360. If I understood what you want correctly, something like this should work:

```py
# get values from database into a dictionary
planets = {
    "Sun": 135.45,
    "Mars": 29.72,
    "Jupiter": 56.89,
    "Uranus": 45.27,
    "Pluto": 165.78,
    "Venus": 89.34,
    "Mercury": 312.22,
    "Saturn": 267.86,
    "Moon": 92.78,
    "Earth": 33.23
}

# this function returns true if the difference between two planets' degrees is 
# withing the range from 0 to degrees or within 360 - degrees and 360

def aspect(planet1, planet2, degrees):
    diff = abs(planets[planet1] - planets[planet2]) % 360
    return diff <= degrees or diff >= 360 - degrees

for planet1 in planets:
    for planet2 in planets:
        if planet1 != planet2:
            if aspect(planet1, planet2, 90):
                print(f"{planet1} and {planet2} are in a square aspect")
            elif aspect(planet1, planet2, 60):
                print(f"{planet1} and {planet2} are in a sextile aspect")
            elif aspect(planet1, planet2, 30):
                print(f"{planet1} and {planet2} are in a trine aspect")
```

This will output the aspects between all the planets in the dictionary planets. You can adjust the degrees parameter to match the aspect you want to calculate.

Comment: Thanks FranFrancisco9. this snippet really helped me to understand the approach to use. I apologize to you too if I mistakenly mistaken the section in which to ask the question. However you have been very helpful. ✌